# Detect When AVFoundation Camera Finishes Focusing

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I currently am using AVFoundation to run my camera, but I want to be able to detect when the camera finishes focusing. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html)

> You can use the `adjustingFocus` property to determine whether a device
>   is currently focusing. You can observe the property using `key-value observing` to be notified when a device starts and stops focusing.
>
> If you change the focus mode settings, you can return them to the
>   default configuration as follows:

Comment: I guess it merits to expand upon Shubhank answer for those like me who don't like to read the apple (excellent) documentation suggesting for a few purposes to discard frames that came while the AVCaptureDevice was adjusting exposure and, possibly, whitepoint

Answer (score 8):

In the initialisation:

```
[[[captureManager videoInput] device] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"adjustingFocus" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

and then:

```
bool focusing = false;  
bool finishedFocus = false;
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    //[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"adjustingFocus"] ){
        BOOL adjustingFocus = [ [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] ];

        if (adjustingFocus) {
             focusing=true;
        }
        else {
           if (focusing) {
                focusing = false;
                finishedFocus = true;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @alexi-akl ! This was the code I was missing... :)

Comment: glad my answer was helpful :) @cdescours